# XML -> TXT via XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am starting to work on a project where I receive data in XML, which has to be translated into a text file that represents python to be executed.

I came across this:

[XML To Text](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/docbook-apps/2001-q3/msg00141.html)

and wonder what XSLT experts think about it. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is a little bit too general. The answer is equally general: "Yes, one can use XSLT to produce any text". It is likely that you need more specific answers to a more specific question. To get these, please, edit the question and give us a specific example of the text to be processed (short, please) and the exact wanted result from the transformation. Any rules that the transformation must implement in producing the result from the input should be provided and explained.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The question has to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422486/design-pattern-advice-graph-computation Here the graph data is XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Producing a python script via XSLT is entirely possible.**

`text` is one of the choices for the method (i.e. format) in [`xsl:output`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-output)

You use it in your stylesheet like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>   

   <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:text>#!/usr/bin/env python&#xA;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:text># This program is a "Hello World" example&#xA;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:text>print 'Hello world!'</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above stylesheet produces the following Python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# This program is a "Hello World" example
print 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: This doesn't actually transform any input, it's just writing out hardcoded python from the stylesheet.

Comment: @Jim Garrison - yes, it was intended to be a very simple proof of concept to demonstrate that a Python script could be generated with `method="text"`. If sample XML and/or output Python were provided I would have provided a more realistic example.